# Figure sizes with pandoc conversion from markdown to docx

Tags: image, markdown, docx, knitr, pandoc

I type a report with Rmarkdown in Rstudio. When converting it in `html` with knitr, there is also a `markdown` file produced by knitr. I convert this file with `pandoc` as follows :

```
pandoc -f markdown -t docx input.md -o output.docx
```

The `output.docx` file is nice except for one problem: the sizes of the figures are altered, I need to manually resize the figures in Word. Is there something to do, maybe an option with `pandoc`, to get the right figures sizes ?

Comment: Which version of Pandoc are you using? If using an outdated version, a possible workaround would be to render smaller images inside of `knitr`.

Comment: This is version 1.9.4.2. I don't want to change the sizes inside of `knitr` because the sizes are well in the output html file.

Comment: I have tried the latest (Windows) Pandoc version now. That does not change anything.

Comment: I would love to find an answer to this question...

Comment: @TalGalili Please see my solution using ImageMagick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An easy way consists in including a scale factor `k` in the individual chunk options:

```
{r, fig.width=8*k, fig.height=6*k}
```

and a variable `dpi` in the global chunk options:

```
opts_chunk$set(dpi = dpi)
```

Then you can set the values of `dpi` and `k` before knitting the `Rmd` file in the global environment:

```
dpi <<- 96    
k <<- 1
```

or you can set them in a chunk in the `Rmd` file (set `k` in the first chunk for example).

Answer (score 4):

I also want to transform an R markdown into both an html and a .docx/.odt  with figures at the good size and resolution. Until now,  I found that the best way to do this is define explicitly the resolution and size of the graphs in the .md document (dpi, fig.width and fig.height options). If you do this you have good graphs usable for publication and the odt/docx is ok. The problem if you use dpi much higher than the default 72 dpi, is that the graphs will look too big in the html file. Here are 3 approaches I have used to handle this (NB I use R scripts with spin() syntax):

1) use out.extra ='WIDTH="75%"' in knitr options. This will force all graphs of the html to occupy 75% of the window width. This is a quick solution but not optimal if you have plots with very different sizes. (NB I prefer working with centimetres rather than inches, hence the /2.54 everywhere)

```
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, dev = c("png", "pdf"), dpi = 400,
               fig.width = 8/2.54, fig.height = 8/2.54,
               out.extra ='WIDTH="75%"'
)

data(iris)

#' # Iris datatset
summary(iris)
boxplot(iris[,1:4])

#+ fig.width=14/2.54, fig.height=10/2.54
par(mar = c(2,2,2,2))
pairs(iris[,-5])
```

2)  use out.width and out.height to specify the size of the graphs in pixels into the html file. I use a constant "sc" to scale down the size of the plot into the html output. This is the more precise approach but the problem is that for each graph you have to define both fig.witdth/height and out.width/height and this is really boaring ! Ideally you should be able to specify in the global options that e.g. out.width = 150*fig.width (where fig.width changes from chunk to chunk). Maybe something like that is possible but I don't know how.

```
#+ echo = FALSE
library(knitr)
sc <- 150
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, dev = c("png", "pdf"), dpi = 400,
                fig.width = 8/2.54, fig.height = 8/2.54,
                out.width = sc*8/2.54, out.height = sc*8/2.54
)

data(iris)

#' # Iris datatset
summary(iris)
boxplot(iris[,1:4])

#+ fig.width=14/2.54, fig.height=10/2.54, out.width= sc * 14/2.54, out.height= sc * 10/2.54
par(mar = c(2,2,2,2))
pairs(iris[,-5])
```

Note that for these two solution, I think that you can't transform directly your md file into odt with pandoc (the figures are not included). I transform the md into html and then the html into odt (didn't tried for docx).
Something like that (if the previous R scripts is names "figsize1.R") :

```
library(knitr)
setwd("/home/gilles/")
spin("figsize1.R")

system("pandoc figsize1.md -o figsize1.html")
system("pandoc figsize1.html -o figsize1.odt")
```

3) Simply compile your document twice, once with low dpi value (~96) for the html output and once with high resolution (~300) for the odt/docx output. This is my preferred way now. The main disadvantage is that you must compile twice but this is not reallya problem to me since I generally need the odt file only at the very end of the job to provide to end users. I compile regularly the html during the work with the html notebook button in Rstudio.

```
#+ echo = FALSE
library(knitr)

opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, dev = c("png", "pdf"), 
               fig.width = 8/2.54, fig.height = 8/2.54
)

data(iris)

#' # Iris datatset
summary(iris)
boxplot(iris[,1:4])

#+ fig.width=14/2.54, fig.height=10/2.54
par(mar = c(2,2,2,2))
pairs(iris[,-5])
```

Then compile the 2 outputs with the following script (NB here you can directly transform the md file into html):

```
library(knitr)
setwd("/home/gilles")

opts_chunk$set(dpi=96)
spin("figsize3.R", knit=FALSE)
knit2html("figsize3.Rmd")

opts_chunk$set(dpi=400)
spin("figsize3.R")
system("pandoc figsize3.md -o figsize3.odt")
```

Comment: Great ideas, thank you. I'll try soon. And welcome to the site :)

Comment: Hello Gilles. I have tried your third solution but that does not change the size. Maybe I don't follow correctly your procedure: I put `opts_chunk$set` in the first chunk of my `Rmd` file. The size is increased in the html output but not in the docx (only quality is increased).

Comment: Which of the 3 solutions did you tried ? Did you specify different `fig.width/fig.height` and/or `out.width/out.height` in the different code chunks ?

Comment: The third solution. Yes I always specify `fig.width` and `fig.height` in each chunk (but not `out.width` and `out.height`).

Comment: Finally I increase the quality with `dpi=400` and then I resize following my answer with ImageMagick.

Comment: I don't understand. Did you tried to reproduce my exact example ? I get an odt or docx file with one 8 cm fig and one 14 cm fig and high resolution. No need to resize them. Or can you provide a reproducible example that do not work ? If you want to compile twice with different dpi values, the dpi argument should not be specified in the `opts_chunk$set` in your Rmd file but well in the just before using the knit functions.

Comment: Hi. Ok, I have not run `opts_chunk$set` before knitting. I'll try next time.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution to resize the figures using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) from an R Script. The 70% ratio seems to be a nice choice.

```
# the path containing the Rmd file :
wd <- "..."
setwd(wd)

# the folder containing the figures :
fig.path <- paste0(wd, "/figure")
# all png figures :
figures <- list.files(fig.path, pattern=".png", all.files=TRUE)

# (safety) create copies of the original files
dir.create(paste0(fig.path,"_copy"))
for(i in 1:length(figures)){
  fig <- paste0(fig.path, "/", figures[i])
  file.copy(fig,"figure_copy")
}

# resize all figures
for(i in 1:length(figures)){
    fig <- paste0(fig.path, "/", figures[i])
    comm <- paste("convert -resize 70%", fig, fig)
    shell(comm)
}

# then run pandoc from a command line  
# or from the pandoc() function :
library(knitr)
pandoc("MyReport.md", "docx")
```

More info about the `resize` function of ImageMagick : [www.perturb.org](http://www.perturb.org/display/632_ImageMagick_resize_images.html)

Comment: BTW, I've added ImageMagick as one of the supported software in the installr package. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/installr/

Comment: @TalGalili Thanks. However I'm afraid there's a loss of quality when resizing with `convert -resize 70% fig1.png fig1.png`

Comment: Why someone has downvoted this answer ? It works, I often use it now, and it solves the question. So why ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, somehow missclicked. When I had noted it, I could not revert, too bad. @Tal Galili: Please vote + for me as a compensation. The argument of "loss of quality" is valid though.

Comment: @DieterMenne Maybe there's an ImageMagick option to increase quality.

Comment: No, there is none. Pixel graphics scale badly, and I would not recommend sending it to some high-ranking journal after rescaling.

Comment: @DieterMenne Thanks. Good to know. And if I increase the png resolution in R, can I expect a good quality after resizing with ImageMagick ?

Comment: Yes, but it is not worth the effort. The only perfect method is creating pdf or eps, and doing the conversion to the final size from these. This will always produce perfect output (well, not for final 10x10pixels :]). It should be possible to modify you concept that way, but note that you need Ghostscript installed in addition to Imagemagick.

Comment: @DieterMenne I think that `knit2html()` is not able to convert (R)Markdown to HTML with pdf figures (surely impossible vith eps). And is it possible to do a Markdown file with pdf figures and to convert it in docx with pandoc ? I recall that the question is to find a way to go from RMarkdown to html with Rstudio and then to get a docx output.

Comment: Just to say - my personal need for this solution is for quick reports for people I work with. For that purpose, this is a nice solution...

Comment: I was thinking of a hook (http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks); sorry I have no time to test this, and I rarely use Word. However, are you sure you have tested the combinations of out.width and fig.width with Word/Pandoc?

Comment: @DieterMenne I want the HTML output **and** the docx output, both with correct figure sizes (possibly one could run the compilation twice with a different hook, why not)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution: hack the docx converted by Pandoc, as docx is simply a bundle of xml files and adjusting the figure sizes is pretty straightforward.

The following is what a figure looks like in the `word/document.xml` extracted from a converted docx:

```
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:drawing>
      <wp:inline>
        <wp:extent cx="1524000" cy="1524000" />
        ...
        <a:graphic>
          <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
            <pic:pic>
              ...
              <pic:blipFill>
                <a:blip r:embed="rId23" />
                ...
              </pic:blipFill>
              <pic:spPr bwMode="auto">
                <a:xfrm>
                  <a:off x="0" y="0" />
                  <a:ext cx="1524000" cy="1524000" />
                </a:xfrm>
                ...
              </pic:spPr>
            </pic:pic>
          </a:graphicData>
        </a:graphic>
      </wp:inline>
    </w:drawing>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

So substituting the `cx` & `cy` attributes of the nodes `wp:extent` & `a:ext` with desired value would do the resizing job. The following R code works for me. The widest figure would take up a whole line's width specified by the variable `out.width`, and the rest are proportionally resized.

```
require(XML)

## default linewidth (inch) for Word 2003
out.width <- 5.77
docx.file <- "report.docx"

## unzip the docx converted by Pandoc
system(paste("unzip", docx.file, "-d temp_dir"))
document.xml <- "temp_dir/word/document.xml"
doc <- xmlParse(document.xml)
wp.extent <- getNodeSet(xmlRoot(doc), "//wp:extent")
a.blip <- getNodeSet(xmlRoot(doc), "//a:blip")
a.ext <- getNodeSet(xmlRoot(doc), "//a:ext")

figid <- sapply(a.blip, xmlGetAttr, "r:embed")
figname <- dir("temp_dir/word/media/")
stopifnot(length(figid) == length(figname))
pdffig <- paste("temp_dir/word/media/",
                ## in case figure ids in docx are not in dir'ed order
                sort(figname)[match(figid, substr(figname, 1, nchar(figname) - 4))], sep="")

## get dimension info of included pdf figures
pdfsize <- do.call(rbind, lapply(pdffig, function (x) {
    fig.ext <- substr(x, nchar(x) - 2, nchar(x))
    pp <- pipe(paste(ifelse(fig.ext == 'pdf', "pdfinfo", "file"), x, sep=" "))
    pdfinfo <- readLines(pp); close(pp)
    sizestr <- unlist(regmatches(pdfinfo, gregexpr("[[:digit:].]+ X [[:digit:].]+", pdfinfo, ignore.case=T)))
    as.numeric(strsplit(sizestr, split=" x ")[[1]])
}))

## resizing pdf figures in xml DOM, with the widest figure taking up a line's width
wp.cx <- round(out.width*914400*pdfsize[,1]/max(pdfsize[,1]))
wp.cy <- round(wp.cx*pdfsize[, 2]/pdfsize[, 1])
wp.cx <- as.character(wp.cx)
wp.cy <- as.character(wp.cy)
sapply(1:length(wp.extent), function (i)
       xmlAttrs(wp.extent[[i]]) <- c(cx = wp.cx[i], cy = wp.cy[i]));
sapply(1:length(a.ext), function (i)
       xmlAttrs(a.ext[[i]]) <- c(cx = wp.cx[i], cy = wp.cy[i]));

## save hacked xml back to docx
saveXML(doc, document.xml, indent = F)
setwd("temp_dir")
system(paste("zip -r ../", docx.file, " *", sep=""))
setwd("..")
system("rm -fr temp_dir")
```

Comment: Hello. I have not tried yet but anyway this looks like a great job (+1).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Hope my code explains itself. Here only pdf figures are considered. Since shrunk figures maintain relative sizes to each other, if the widest figure is too large, the others would look very small in the final docx. Please keep this in mind.

Comment: Pdf figures ? Only png figures are generated.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, please see my updated code. It now handles both pdf and non-pdf figures, still with the widest taking up a whole line of width and the rest resized proportionally.